# Binding a Collection<bool> to togglebuttons/checkboxed

Tags: c#, wpf, collections, binding, boolean

I have a collection of bools associated to days of the week - Collection() { true, false, false, false, false, false,false}; So whatever the bool represents means that this collection applies for sunday (sunday being the first day of week here).

Now I have set the itemssource of my listbox, say, to be this collection.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource={Binding Path=Collection, Mode=TwoWay}>
     <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
         <ToggleButton IsChecked={Binding Path=BoolValue, Mode=TwoWay}/>
     </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

However my Collection never gets updated (my collection is a dependencyproperty on the window). Plus "MyBool" class is simply just a wrapper around a bool object, with NotifyPropertyChanged implemented.

Any ideas.....my actual code is majorly complex so the above situation is a brutally simplified version, so make assumptions etc if necessary Ill work around this given that I have provided my actual code.

Thanks greatly in advance,

U.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged in your binding

```
<ToggleButton IsChecked={Binding Path=BoolValue, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}/>
```

edit:
created a small example, seems fine.

The wrapper class

```
    public class MyBool : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _value;

    public bool Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set
        {
            _value = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Value");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

The XAML

```
       <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Users}" >
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <ToggleButton IsChecked="{Binding Path=Value, Mode=TwoWay}" Content="MyButton"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Code behind

```
 /// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<MyBool> Users { get; set; }
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Users = new ObservableCollection<MyBool>();
        DataContext = this;
        Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainWindow_Loaded);

    }

    void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        FillUsers();
    }

    private void FillUsers()
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            if(i%2 == 0)
                Users.Add(new MyBool { Value = true });
            else
                Users.Add(new MyBool {  Value = false});
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That also seems to do nothing im afraid....going to take another look in the morning so if discover anything Ill reply

Comment: I cant seem to do this without some sort of code behind to help with the updating....does anyone have any idea with direct binding???

Thanks U

Comment: Its very similar....I cant give you the exact code due to copyright problems etc. I just really want to know how to approach such a binding. I have an object with a colection of bools, bound to a set of 7 togglebutton, how is the updating logic performed?

Comment: Any ideas? Anyone? Im stuck here...can seem to perform the the two way binding without some hack.....

Comment: The update logic is gained by the type in the collection implementing INotifyPropertyChanged, bool does not do this and thus must be wrapped in a class which does.